# Converting X/Y coordinates using pyproj giving incorrect results

Tags: python, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, pyproj, xy

I have two CSV files which I have to merge and the only thing common I found was one of them has coordinates of six points for polygon.

[image: screenshot from 1st csv]

and the second file has x, y coordinates which is the only thing I think should be common to merge these two files.

[image: screenshot from 2nd csv]

But the problem is that when I convert the x y coordinates from the 2nd CSV using this snippet

```py
def xy_to_lonlat(x, y):
   proj_latlon = pyproj.Proj(proj='latlong',datum='WGS84')
   proj_xy = pyproj.Proj(proj="utm", zone='42N', 
   datum='WGS84')
   lonlat = pyproj.transform(proj_xy, proj_latlon, x, y)
   return lonlat[0], lonlat[1]
```

It yields value from `(121.31518977062919, 27.639463664699907)` to `(66.33097901551467, 38.87383705538533)`. So this conversion is not matching the values from the 1st file. Is this the correct approach or is there any other way I can merge these files?

Comment: maybe they are not UTM-42N? where do you expect them to be? is there any metadata?

Comment: I checked for the region details so according to it uzbekhistan lies in the 42N region. I am not from a GIS background so I don't exactly know whether the provided co-ordinates are in the UTM system. Also, No other metadata is provided sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the conversion with

```
gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:32642 -t_srs EPSG:4326
Enter X Y [Z [T]] values separated by space, and press Return.
6048633 4502820
121.315000487376 27.6395619368755 0
```

The result is the same that you got so sadly it seems that the coordinates in the table are not in EPSG:32642 (WGS 84 / UTM zone 42N).